# Sphinx Search use sql_attr_* without returning field?

Tags: php, sphinx

I want to use a filter on an attribute `sql_attr_uint`, which is received from the `sql_query` in my config.

Everything works great using the PHP API (latest on the Git repos), apart from one thing. Because my site wasn't originally written to accomodate this extra 'field' (following from another question I'm using the crc32 of a string instead of doing exact ^string$ matching), it means my `$SphinxSearch->search(...);` is returning an additional column than necessary.

However if I remove the sql_attr_uint line for the CRC32 field of course I can't perform filtering on it.

Short of going through the results array and unsetting all the elements with the crc32 value in so my array indicies line up again, is there a way to simply ignore the attribute field from the results? Perhaps something like:

`sql_attr_uint_silent = somefield`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetSelect can be used to control which attributes are returned. Setting to empty string should give you none.